# What is the word that means of or pertaining to bushes?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology

I recall a long time ago reading a science-fiction book that contained a word to describe a character that I didn't recognise. When I looked it up, I learned it meant 'of or pertaining to bushes.'

It was a word ending in '-ine' like psittacine (pertaining to parrots) or ursine (pertaining to bears) but I can't for the life of me remember what it was.

It's also proving impossible to google, with results ranging from "just use 'bushy' you cabbage" to pejoratives for certain US presidents...

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just  a guess, **bushline** - The altitude above which indigenous forest does not grow *or* the contour at which the growth of the bush ceases?

Comment: If you'd recognise it if you saw a part of it, it might be worth looking up Latin translations of "bush" or "shrub".

Comment: The two most common Latin words for a bush or shrub that I can think of or find are _dūmus_ (earlier _dusmus_) and _frutex_, but neither of those really has an _-ine_ derivative. There’s _dūmalis_ in Latin which might have given either _dumal_ or further derived _dumaline_ in English, but that doesn’t seem to exist (except, ironically, as a name, but that seems to be a variant of _du Moulin_ ‘Miller’).

Comment: Is it possible that the word wasn't about bushes per se, but about bushy hair? I know that L. Sprague de Camp coined the word "hyperpilosity" in the story "Hyperpilosity", for example.

Comment: I tried. I found "alpine", "subalpine", and "sylvan". Do these help in any way?

Comment: I would say "bushy".

Comment: @HotLicks: Agreed.  Not ending in "-ine". But "of or pertaining to bushes" is exactly "bushy".

Comment: If you can remember more about the story, you might get an answer on Fantasy and Science Fiction SE.   People there have amazing memories about any story ever published.

Comment: long shot :  [lignine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lignin).  See under History.

Answer (score 2):

*Sylvestral* means *of, like or pertaining to trees.* But, I haven't came across any word ending with *-ine* that defines "of, like or pertaining to bushes." Similarly, I haven't came across any words which means "of, like or pertaining to "shrubs", or "herbs", or "plants", or "weeds" etc.

Perhaps, the word **dumose** or **dumous** from *latine* ***dumosus***,  *franch* ***dumus*** meaning a thornbush, a bramble is defined in Webster 1913 as:

From Webster 1913
https://www.websters1913.com/words/Dumose

> (Botany) Having a compact, bushy form.

As you say, you found this word in a science fiction book. The author might have coined the term to mean- *of, or relating to bushes.*

---

*NOTE:* We can form a word: dumosusine or dumusine, by adding suffix [*-ine*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ine) meaning *of or relating to bushes*. Though, Google presents no search results of dumosusine or dumusine.

Answer (score -1):

In science, the word commonly used to describe “bushy” (branching) structures is ***dendritic.***  It derives from the Ancient Greek *dendron,* meaning “tree” rather than “bush”, and it doesn’t end in -ine, so it is presumably not the word you saw.

I can’t easily find uses of “haimine”, “auline”, “thamnine” or “rhopine” (plausible Greek-rooted words for “bushy”), nor for “fruticine”, “paliurine” or “arbusculine” (Latin), though Wiktionary does list [arbuscular](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/arbuscular).  I think the suffix -ine is more common in adjectives with Latin roots, or at least, I can’t think of any Greek examples.

It may have been a word whose root doesn’t exactly mean “bush”, or a variation of one of the forms I tried, or based on a root that didn’t appear on sites I searched.